# How do you tell cordova plugin add to pull a specific version of a plugin

Tags: plugins, cordova, command-line-interface

Cordova provides a CLI which allows you add plugins to your project like so:

```
cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-file
```

This adds the latest version of the file plugin for example.

My question is how do you tell it to add a specific version of the file plugin for example file-r0.2.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-file@0.2.5
```

check the cordova docs : http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface_advanced_plugin_options